# Logging in with G+ - why scope "plus.login" won't work alone?

Tags: android, google-api, google-plus, google-plus-signin

I have gone through dozens of answers on the topic, followed the official quick start guide, and done all I could think of.

I have set up my google developer console in all its parts, including setting right debug SHA1 keys for both OAuth and Public API Access (don't even know if that was necessary).

### Issue

I have issues setting scopes to my `GoogleApiClient`.

```
googleClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .addApi(Plus.API)
        .addScope(...)
        .build();
```

I can login with different combinations of scopes:

```
            .addScope(new Scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login"))
            .addScope(new Scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read"))
            //WORKS! OR:

            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN) // == https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE) // == https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me
            //WORKS! OR:

            .addScope(new Scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read"))
            //WORKS! OR:

            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE) // == https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me
            //WORKS!
```

They all work well and I see them reflected in the requests (i.e., if I set `login` + `emails.read`, the dialog will actually ask for these two).

However, I only need "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login". If I just set `.addScope(new Scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login"))` , or equivalently, `.addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)`, I encounter the well-document Toast error:

> Internal error occurred.

So this scope (the only one I need) works in conjunction with others (e.g. plus.me), but not alone. Why is that, and what can I do?

Comment: I have derived the same conclusions as you and still no answer. I ended up adding both Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE and Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN because Login by itself results in null resolution. I haven't found a reason or solution for why this is yet.

Answer (score 0):

you  can replace this code by the following which worked for me.

```
   mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Plus.API, Plus.PlusOptions.builder().build())
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).build();
```

Answer (score 0):

> mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
>               .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
>               .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
>               .addApi(Plus.API, Plus.PlusOptions.builder().build())
>               .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).build();

Using Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN is not a good idea as 'Plus' is deprecated.